# How to restrict only a Layer Group instead of giving the whole service when loading a WMS on qgis?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, group-layer

I created a workspace, a store and some layers on GeoServer. Then I created a layer group and added a few layers.
When I try to load a specific layer on QGIS I use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspacename/layername/wms
```

and everything works fine, I do the connection and is listed only the layer I want and not the whole service layers.
Now I want to do the same for a layer group, I want that only a specific layer group be listed when I click on connect button.
However, if I do the same as above:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspacename/layergroupname/wms
```

it gives an error.

In OpenLayers, the layer group is correctly loaded when I do the layer preview in GeoServer, and the resulting URL is the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=workspace:layergroupname&styles=&bbox=-25.1745333333,30.02271667,-15.85316667,37.2715666667&width=768&height=597&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers
```

but using this URL on QGIS when loading the service, the whole service layers are listed and not just the group layer I want.

How can I restrict to a layer group when loading a WMS service into QGIS?

Comment: In QGIS (in any WMS client) you can only use the GetCapabilities endpoint to define the data source.  But when you select the data, you can just select the data (group layer, layer, or style in a layer) you want to view.  If a layer has a name you can select it directly in clients such as  OL to create your map.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. What I need is to list only a layer group and not the whole service content when connect with a WMS on QGIS. For a layer it works fine using this URL http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspacename/layername/wms, but for a layer group does not. What should I do?

Comment: I know that after listing all service content when doing the service connection, I can select the layers I want to load. But that is not my problem. What I want is to restrict the URL in order to list only a specific layer group when doing the connection.

Comment: _What I need is to list only a layer group and not the whole service content when connect with a WMS on QGIS_ Why?

Comment: Because I want it! If you don't know how to do it, let others answer.

Comment: Yes, but the reason might influence the answer :)

Comment: The reason is that however the service contains several layers and layer groups inside, I want to restrict the URL that I will provide to someone to open it in qgis with only the layer group I want.

Comment: Reference to GeoServer documentation:http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/virtual-services.html. Layer groups are not mentioned there so perhaps it is just a missing feature. You can use security system or the new GeoFence module for creating users and roles.

Comment: Yes... as you say, in fact layer groups are not mentioned in the filtering... pity... as we can do the filtering by layer in the URL of the WMS service, it would be very useful for me to do that filtering by layer group... My idea is to add several layers of datasets of species to a workspace and then to group those layers into layer groups such as 'Protected species', 'Dangerous species', 'Marine species', and so on, and then distribute the URLs of those layer groups.

Comment: ...distribute the URLs of those layer groups separately! I'm afraid I'll have to create a wokspace per service I want to provide, i.e., a workspace for DangerousSpecies, another for MarineSpecies, and so on... unfortunately I think this is unnecessarily redundant because I will have to repeat the addition of several layers into those workspaces...